# Prof Lawrence Shampine's hpde matlab code

Tags: pde, matlab, numerics

Where can one find Prof Lawrence Shampine's hpde matlab code?

Is it well received? It's not commonly talked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a zip archive on the Wayback Machine from Shampine’s homepage in 2010:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100624204352/http://faculty.smu.edu/shampine/hpde.zip